# Socket.io and Express callbacks from endpoint

Tags: express, socket.io

here is my scenario. I have a simple express/socket.io app and some python clients (using python-socketio) that needs to be updated whenever a user visit my only endpoint.

After a socket connection I'm saving the `socket.id` in an array in order to emit from my post route to one specific client.

```js
let sockets = []

app.post('/confirm/', (req, res) => {

  // Get destination socket
  socket_id = sockets[0] // testing purpose

  io.to(socket_id).emit('confirm', {
    'order_id': 'a8hds87',
  })
})

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('user connected');
  sockets.push(socket.id)
});
```

Now this is working fine but now I'm stuck trying to define a callback on my emit. If I try to add a callback like the following Node keeps telling me that `Callbacks are not supported when broadcasting`. However, since I'm targetting specific client with `to(socket_id)` this error seems strange to a novice like me. Where am I wrong?

```js
io.to(socket_id).emit('confirm', {
  'order_id': 'a8hds87',
}, (callback) => {
  // my callback
})
```

Comment: Why don't you just push the actual socket object itself into the array rather than pushing the ID.  Then you can use `socket.emit()` which will support a callback.  Also, I presume you know that when a socket disconnects, you need to remove it from your array.

Answer (score 0):

You can push the actual socket object itself into the array rather than pushing the ID. Then you can use `socket.emit()` which will support a callback.

The issue with `io.to().emit()` is that it returns a `BroadcastOperator` object which only knows how to `.emit()` to rooms (a `socket.id` is also a room name that contains only one socket).

And, I presume you know that when a socket disconnects, you need to remove it from your array.

---

I just discovered a new method in recent versions of socket.io [`.allSockets()`](https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-api/#namespace-allSockets).  So, using that you could also do this:

```
const socket = Array.from(io.to(socket_id).allSockets())[0];
socket.emit(msg, data, callback);
```

Seems like kind of a hack, but it would convert a `socket_id` into the `socket` object.